# Unable to run Python files in terminal of VSC

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

i have installed VSC and set up the necessary dependencies for python.
Using a simple hello world example, i can run the file using run and debug option.
I can also run it by manually typing python hello.py in the terminal.
However, when i use the run button (top right hand corner), i get an error.

[image: Run button and error msg]

Can i check how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I could see in the image that you able to print "test2" . so whats the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Hi @ShekharSamanta, the test2 is the output when i type in the terminal "python hello.py" and press enter, i.e. it works fine. But when i try to run it using the run button (top right hand corner), i get the error msg (in red). While it isn't a big deal, I would like to rectify why the run button doesn't work as it should.

Comment: i know its an old question, but just FYI : always include paths under double quotes ""

I can see in the above image - Folder name : Tian'En is causing the error as it already includes single quote which breaks the absolute path